# How to decode a messed up UTF-8 string properly?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, exif, iptc

I'm trying to read IPTC data using python and pyexiv2.

```
import pyexiv2
image = pyexiv2.Image('test.jpg')
image.readMetadata()
print image['Iptc.Application2.Caption']
```

That gives me thefollwing:

```
Copyright: Michael Huebner, Kontakt: +4915100000000xxxxxx Höxx (30) ist im Streit mit dem Arbeitsamt in Brandenburg, xxxxxxxxxxxxxx , xxxxxx,
```

But it is supposed to give me:

```
Kinder: Axxxxx Hxxxxx (10) und Exxxxxx Höxx (5), Rxxxxxxx Höxx (30) ist im Streit mit dem Arbeitsamt in Brandenburg, xxxxxxxxxxxxx , xxxxxxxxxxx, 
Copyright: Michael Huebner, Kontakt: +4915100000000
```

It's a bit messy, because I had to remove personal data, but you can see what had happened: The 'newline' makes the last part override the first part of the string.

But now it gets weird:

```
for i in str(image['Iptc.Application2.Caption']):
  print i,
```

That just prints out all characters including the newline in the correct order. But it messes up the "Umlaut" characters.

This:

```
unicode(image['Iptc.Application2.Caption'])
```

Gives me:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So how can I have both: Umlaut and correct string oder? How can I fix this string?

Comment: Don't use a blockquote if you need to include newlines in output.

Comment: What does `print repr(image['Iptc.Application2.Caption'])` show is in the string? You probably have a `\r` in there, a carriage return.

Comment: Yes, it's \r. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data uses a different line separator convention from what you are expecting. This is not a UTF-8 specific problem, really.

You can split your lines using `str.splitlines()`; it'll recognize `\r` as line separators. Optionally, you can *rejoin* your lines with `\n`:

```
>>> sample = 'line 1\rline 2'
>>> print sample
line 2
>>> sample.splitlines()
['line 1', 'line 2']
>>> print '\n'.join(sample.splitlines())
line 1
line 2
```